# error when call python object thru MEL code

Tags: python, maya

How to resolve this.

```
Following error occurs from maya. I am doing the following in Filemenu.mel file. this runs at the startup.
```

python("import saveCentral_fromPath");
.
.
.

global proc runSaveCentral()
{

```
python("saveCentral_fromPath.saveCentral()");
python("a._first_()");
```

}

.
.
.
        menuItem -label ("save Central") -en 1
            -annotation ("publish : copy to central area")
            -command ("runSaveCentral()") publishItem;

```
# Error: file: S:/xxxxxxxx/scripts/maya/melTEST/FileMenu.mel line 64: class saveCentral_fromPath has no attribute 'saveCentral'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# AttributeError: class saveCentral_fromPath has no attribute 'saveCentral' #
```

Brgds,

kNish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python("import saveCentral_fromPath");
.
..

global proc runSaveCentral()

{
    python("saveCentral_fromPath.saveCentral()._first_()");
#               filename.classname.functionname
}

.
.
.
menuItem -label ("save Central") -en 1
-annotation ("publish : copy to central area")
-command ("runSaveCentral()") publishItem;
```